# React local JSON data filtering using usEffect Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks, filtering

I've been working on a user display for an engineering page and was trying to display and filter the data based on the following criteria of field and expertise. Fields can be filtered through the selection of a dropdown menu while expertise can be filtered via input. I initially wanted to load just the default json file onto the page once the user reaches the page, and then filter this data based on whatever filters the user has selected. I figured the best approach to do this would be via a useEffect hook, but for whatever reason when I follow this route, the initial data being loaded is not all the data from the local json file and returns a single card with empty values. In addition, I also been running into an issue where the user decides to filter both by field and expertise which results in an error and crashes the page. If anyone could provide assistance or guidance on how to implement multiple filtering via useEffect hooks would be greatly appreciated!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; 
import { Row, Col, Container } from "react-bootstrap";


import "./engineerDashboard.css"; // Import styling
import engineerData from "./EngineerDashboard.json"


function EngineerDashboard() {


    const [searchSelect, setSearchSelect] = useState('');
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
    const [engineers, setEngineers] = useState([engineerData]);
    const [sortedEngineers, setSortedEngineers] = useState([]);

    console.log(sortedEngineers)
    

    
    useEffect(() => {
        let result = [...engineers];
    
        if(searchInput) {
          result = result[0].engineers.filter(item => item.tools === searchInput);      
        }
    
        if(searchSelect) {
          result = result[0].engineers.filter(item => item.field === searchSelect);      
        }
        setSortedEngineers(result);
    
    }, [searchSelect, engineers, searchInput]);
    

    return (
        <div>
            <Container fluid className="content-block">
            
            <Container fluid className="header-block">
                <Row >
                    <h2>Find Engineers</h2>

                    <Col sm={3}>
                        <div className="pageHeaderComponent">
                            <p className="componentLabel">Field:</p>
                            <select 
                                className="search-select"
                                onChange={e => setSearchSelect(e.target.value)}    
                            >
                                <option key="Software" value="Software">Software</option>
                                <option key="Design" value="Design">Design</option>
                                <option key="Hardware" value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                                <option key="Cybersecurity" value="Cybersecurity">CyberSecurity</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </Col>

                    <Col sm={3}>
                        <div className="pageHeaderComponent">
                            <p className="componentLabel">Expertise:</p>
                            <input className="search-input" onChange={e => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}></input>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>

              { sortedEngineers.length > 0 &&
                <Row style={{ paddingTop: "20px", marginTop: "20px" }}>
                    { sortedEngineers.map((item, i) => (
                    <Col md={3} sm={6} className="contact-card" key={i}>
                        <div className="inner">
                            <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                            <p className="mt-3 mb-4">Field: {item.field}</p>
                            <p className="mt-3 mb-4">Tools Expertise:</p>
                            <p className="mt-3 mb-4">{item.tools}</p>
                            <p className="mt-3 mb-4">Availability: {item.availability</p>        
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    ))}
                </Row>
                }
                
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EngineerDashboard;
```

Comment: where are you fetching data from json file ?

Comment: i'm importing the data from engineerData via a local json file called ```./EngineerDashboard.json```

Comment: yeah I saw that but where are you using that data in your component I don't see `engineerData` being used anywhere

Comment: its being used when it is initialized for the useState hook of ```engineers``` variable (```const [engineers, setEngineers] = useState([engineerData])```, it is then used in the useEffect hook and set equal to results where this initial data being loaded is filtered and then set equal to ```sortedEngineers```

Comment: ```sortedEngineers``` is then used to map and display the data on the front end which can be seen above

Answer (score 0):

It's showing only one card with no data because you are setting your JSON object inside an array which in terms creates an array with one element. Instead of setting the `engineerData` inside array, set the `engineerData` directly, like this:

```js
const [engineers, setEngineers] = useState(engineerData);
```

I don't have any idea about your JSON file format but you can go from here I guess.

Answer (score 0):

We can make a number of simplifications here that will, as a side-effect (pardon the pun) fix this problem.

You're placing too much into your React state. If your initial engineer data has come from a local JSON file, why then copy it into state in a `useEffect`? Just *use* it!

By the way, there was a clue here - `setEngineers` was never being called.

If we eliminate the `engineers` from your `useEffect`, we get:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let result = [...engineerData];

    if (searchInput) {
      result = engineerData.filter((item) => item.tools === searchInput);
    }

    if (searchSelect) {
      result = engineerData.filter((item) => item.field === searchSelect);
    }
    setSortedEngineers(result);
  }, [searchSelect, searchInput]);
```

This is already better, but we can go further. If you read down your function like React does, nothing is going to be done on the first pass - it's all happening *after* the first render. `sortedEngineers` is really just showing the **result of applying the user's selections** - so why not just make it explicit, remove the `useEffect` entirely, and perform the filter each time React calls us?

```
function EngineerDashboard() {
  const [searchSelect, setSearchSelect] = useState("");
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
  let sortedEngineers = [...engineerData];

  if (searchInput) {
    sortedEngineers = engineerData.filter((item) => item.tools === searchInput);
  }

  if (searchSelect) {
    sortedEngineers = sortedEngineers.filter(
      (item) => item.field === searchSelect
    );
  }

  return (
  ...
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, this definitely works a lot better then what i was originally going for! I was curious that if we were searching for both criteria would you simply do another if statement such as the following ```if (searchSelect && searchInput) ```? also I was wondering when you were making a search via searchInput is there a way to check for individual characters of the string or to see if the string includes what is in the search field? so instead of 100% matching a string like ```adobe xd, react, javascript``` you could search for ```react``` and return a card that has it?